# How can I show user name on gear icon in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, icons, username

I am using ubuntu 12.04 after once used 13.04 one. However, when I login to ubuntu 12.04 and see the gear icon at the right-top of the screen, there is no username on it. How can I fix/show it? Is there any command in Terminal that I should use to restore it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to enable username on top-panel,

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true
```

try this to disable,

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel false
```

Comment: I mean there is no user name label in the right of gear icon. How could be? Is there any different between 13.04 and 12.04? I am sorry I haven't been able to attach the picture yet because I am under 10 reputation.

Comment: upload the image to imgur.com and then post the link here.

Comment: yes normally no username label was present in the right of the gear icon.you have to enable it manually by running the above command.

Comment: link wasn't shown.

Comment: I still can't solve it. Is there any missing thing? I have used the command and even ubuntu tweak tool.

Comment: is there no changes occurs after runnig `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true` command.Are you using gnome version or kde version of ubuntu?

Comment: there is no change even I try to enble from dconf Editor and then I reboot my system. It is still a lonely gear icon without username besides it. I am using gnome version of ubuntu 12.04. Is it because the update that makes some "things" are missed?